# Idempotence question - proof checking

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, idempotents

If $X$ is a symmetric matrix with $X^s = X^{s+1}$ where $s$ is an integer greater than or equal to $1$. Show that $X$ is idempotent.

Attempt:

$X^s = X^{s+1}$

⇒ $XX^s = XX^{s+1}$

⇒ $X^{s+1}$ = $X^{s+2}$

⇒ $XX^s = X^sX^2$

⇒ $X = (X^s)^{-1}X^sX^2$

⇒ $X = IX^2$

⇒ $X = X^2$, therefore $X$ is idempotent.

What makes me think this is wrong is that I haven't used the fact that $X$ is symmetric, which makes me wonder why it is stated in the question. Also it seemed a little too simple and it's easy to make mistakes with Matrix algebra. Would greatly appreciate it if someone can confirm that this is the way to answer this question.

Comment: If $D$ is a diagonal matrix satisfying $D^s=D^{s+1}$ show that the eigenvalues are either $0$ or $1$. Now $X$ is similar to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lozenges! That's a great way to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assumed that $X$ is invertible. This is not allowed.

The proof goes like this:

$X$ is symmetric, hence $X$ is diagonalizable, hence the minimal polnomial splits into distinct linear factors. On the other hand the minimal polynomial is a divisor of $t^s(t-1)$. Thus it is a divisor of $t(t-1)=t^2-t$. Hence $X$ is idempotent.

Actually the proof shows: If $X$ is diagonalizable and $X^s=X^{s+1}$ for some $s \geq 1$, then $X$ is idempotent.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for pointing that out, I will scrap this immediately. I don't understand the logic behind your proof though, most likely because I'm at a lower level. How does that imply idempotency? (Sorry, all I've really learned about it is that if $X = X^2$ then X is idempotent)

Comment: Ok, but you know what a minimal polynomial is?

Comment: Don't think I've heard of it. Is that the same as "quadratic forms"?

Comment: Do you have *any* knowledge about symmetric matrices?

Comment: What is the context of the question?

Comment: Yes I do, some basic theorems. That is the question essentially, almost word for word. No other context

Comment: And now it is my turn to guess which basic theorems you mean?

Comment: Do you know that a symmetric matrix has a basis of eigenvalues?

Comment: "If A is symmetric and  real, then it's eigenvalues are all real, and its eigenvectors are orthogonal."